# How to optimize insert into sql table of 3600 rows from excel file

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I have an Excel file that originally had about 600 rows, and I was able to convert the excel file to a data table and everything got inserted into the sql table correctly.

The Excel file now has 3,600 rows and is having some type of issues that is not throwing an error but after 5 mins or so all the rows are still not inserted into the sql table.

Now, when converting the Excel file to a in memory datatable this happens very quickly, but when looping the datatable and inserting into the sql table is where I'm loosing data and is very slow, but I'm am receiving no errors what so ever.

For one, on each insert I've got to make a new connection to the database and insert the record, and I already know this is very VERY wrong, and I'm hoping to get some guidance from one of the sql pros on this one.

What is the correct way to process a in memory datatable with 3,600 records / rows with-out making 3,600 new connections?

**--Here is the code the processes the excel file, and This happens very quickly.--**

```
public static async Task<DataTable> ProcessExcelToDataTableAsync(string pathAndNewFileName, string hasHeader/*Yes or No*/)
            {

                return await Task.Run(() =>
               {
                   string conStr = "", SheetName = "";

                   switch (Path.GetExtension(pathAndNewFileName))
                   {
                       case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                           conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                           break;
                       case ".xlsx":
                           conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                           break;
                   }
                   conStr = String.Format(conStr, pathAndNewFileName, hasHeader);
                   OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
                   OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
                   OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                   cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                   //Get the name of First Sheet
                   connExcel.Open();
                   DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                   dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                   SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                   connExcel.Close();

                   //Read Data from First Sheet
                   connExcel.Open();
                   cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
                   oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                   oda.Fill(dt);

                   connExcel.Close();
                   cmdExcel.Dispose();
                   oda.Dispose();

                   if (File.Exists(pathAndNewFileName))
                   {
                       File.Delete(pathAndNewFileName);
                   }

                   return dt;
               });
    }
```

--Here is the code that processes the in memory datatable and inserts each new record into the sql table, and this is where things stop working, no visible errors, but just does not return or work--

****I am in need of a better way to optimize this function where the records get inserted into the the sql table.**

```
     static async Task<ProcessDataTablePartsResult> ProcessDataTablePartsAsync(int genericCatalogID, DataTable initialExcelData)
            {
                //@GenericCatalogID   INT,
                //@Number             VARCHAR(50),
                //@Name               VARCHAR(200),
                //@Length             DECIMAL(8,4),
                //@Width              DECIMAL(8,4),
                //@Height             DECIMAL(8,4),
                //@ProfileID          TINYINT,
                //@PackageQty         DECIMAL(9,4),
                //@CategoryID         INT,
                //@UnitMeasure        VARCHAR(10),
                //@Cost               MONEY,
                //@PartID             INT OUT
                return await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    DataTable badDataTable = null,
                              goodDataTable = initialExcelData.Clone();

                    goodDataTable.Clear();

                    int newPartID = 0,
                        currIx = 0,
                        numGoodRows = initialExcelData.Rows.Count,
                        numBadRows = 0;

                    List<int> badIndexes = new List<int>();
                    List<int> goodIndexes = new List<int>();
                    List<Profile> profiles = GenericCatalogManagerBL.GetProfiles(_genericCNN);
                    List<Category> categories = GenericCatalogManagerBL.GetAllCategoryNameID(_genericCNN);

                    Func<string, byte> getProfileID = delegate(string x)
                    {
                        return profiles.Where(p => p.TheProfile.ToLower().Replace(" ", "") == x.ToLower().Replace(" ", "")).FirstOrDefault().ID;
                    };

                    Func<string, int> getCategoryID = delegate(string x)
                    {
                        return categories.Where(c => c.Name.ToLower().Replace(" ", "") == x.ToLower().Replace(" ", "")).FirstOrDefault().ID;
                    };

                    foreach (DataRow r in initialExcelData.Rows)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            IPart p = new Part
                            {
                                GenericCatalogID = genericCatalogID,
                                Number = r["Number"].ToString(),
                                Name = r["Name"].ToString(),
                                Length = decimal.Parse(r["Length"].ToString()),
                                Width = decimal.Parse(r["Width"].ToString()),
                                Height = decimal.Parse(r["Height"].ToString()),
                                ProfileID = getProfileID(r["Profile"].ToString()),
                                CategoryID = getCategoryID(r["Category"].ToString()),
                                PackageQty = int.Parse(r["PackageQty"].ToString()),
                                UnitMeasure = r["UnitMeasure"].ToString(),
                                Cost = decimal.Parse(r["Cost"].ToString())
                            };

                            GenericCatalogManagerBL.InsertPart(_genericCNN, p, out newPartID);
                            goodIndexes.Add(currIx);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            numBadRows++;
                            numGoodRows--;
                            badIndexes.Add(currIx);
                        }
                        currIx++;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < goodIndexes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        goodDataTable.ImportRow(initialExcelData.Rows[goodIndexes[i]]);
                        initialExcelData.Rows[goodIndexes[i]].Delete();

                    }
                    initialExcelData.AcceptChanges();
                    goodDataTable.AcceptChanges();

                    if (initialExcelData.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        badDataTable = initialExcelData;
                    }

                    return new ProcessDataTablePartsResult(numGoodRows, numBadRows, badDataTable, goodDataTable);
                });
            }

**--Here is the entire flow of the function--**

 public static async Task<GenericPartsReport> ProcessGenericPartsAsync(int genericCatalogID, MembershipUser user, HttpRequest request, bool emailReport, bool hasHeaders)
        {
            byte[] fbytes = new byte[request.ContentLength];
            request.InputStream.Read(fbytes, 0, fbytes.Length);

            string pathAndNewFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName() + Path.GetExtension(request.Headers["X-FILE-NAME"]),
                   badReportTableString = "",
                   goodReportTableString = "";

            GenericPartsReport report = new GenericPartsReport();

            //get the users temp folder
            pathAndNewFileName = UtilCommon.SiteHelper.GetUserTempFolder(user, request) + pathAndNewFileName;

            File.WriteAllBytes(pathAndNewFileName, fbytes);

            //process the excel file first
            DataTable excelDataTable = await ProcessExcelToDataTableAsync(pathAndNewFileName, hasHeaders ? "Yes" : "No");

            ProcessDataTablePartsResult processedResult = await ProcessDataTablePartsAsync(genericCatalogID, excelDataTable);

            if (processedResult.BadDataTable != null)
            {
                if (processedResult.BadDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    badReportTableString = await BuildTableReportAsync(processedResult.BadDataTable, "AlumCloud Parts Not Added Report");
                    processedResult.BadDataTable.Dispose();
                }
            }

            if (processedResult.GoodDataTable != null)
            {
                if (processedResult.GoodDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    goodReportTableString = await BuildTableReportAsync(processedResult.GoodDataTable, "AlumCloud Parts Added Report");
                    processedResult.GoodDataTable.Dispose();
                }
            }

            report.Report = "A total number of (" + processedResult.NumberOfGoodRows + ") records was added to your generic catalog.<br/><br/>A total number of (" + processedResult.NumberOfBadRows + ") records were excluded from being added to your generic catalog.";

            if (processedResult.NumberOfBadRows > 0)
            {
                report.Report += "<br/><br/>You can review an excel file that meets the standards here: <a href='" + _exampleExcelFile + "'>How to format a part excel file</a>.";
                report.HasBadRows = true;
            }

            if (processedResult.NumberOfGoodRows > 0)
            {
                report.Report += "<br/><br/><b>Below is all of the parts that were added to your generic catalog<b/><br/><br/>" + goodReportTableString;
            }

            if (processedResult.NumberOfBadRows > 0)
            {
                report.Report += "<br/><br/><b>Below is all of the parts that were not added to your generic catalog</b><br/><br/>" + badReportTableString;
            }

            if (emailReport)
            {
                AFCCIncCommonUtil.EmailUtil.SendMailToThreadPool(user.Email, _supportEmail, report.Report, "AlumCloud Generic Catalog Parts Report", true);
            }

            excelDataTable.Dispose();
            return report;
        }
```

**--This is the function that never returns or is in some state of limbo--**

```
  ProcessDataTablePartsResult processedResult = await ProcessDataTablePartsAsync(genericCatalogID, excelDataTable);
```

Comment: Why aren't you using SSIS to import the data, or even the Import Task from SQL Server Management Studio? 3600 is a negligible amount of data

Comment: So, is the code above doable or do I need to alter it? I never use SSIS, and would have to read up on it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can save the Excel as a CSV and use bcp utility to import data to DB.

Comment: SQL Bulk Copy is also an option here.

Comment: The code is not-quite-comprehensible. I've yet to find the spot where you actually save to the database. With so little data, you can easily do a series of inserts one after the other. There's absolutely no reason to use Tasks. You could even use a Data Adapter to save the data to the database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is right, it'd be much easier to just use the "Import Data" item on the SSMS "Tasks" context menu to import this file.

Comment: Other than a learning experience, any particular reason to use await/async here ? have you considered that this could be your problem ? How about re-implementing all this without it ?

Comment: I am going to need some code from u guys.

Comment: Try with a simple insert, row by row, from the initial table, using the same connection. Can't get any simpler than that.

Comment: Ok, here is what I am doing, I've got sql server manager open and I keep requiring the table the rows are being inserted into and the rows are being inserted, every time I refresh the query I see another 100 rows have been inserted, but when it get to 1000 rows it stopped inserting.

Comment: Never-mind, all of the rows got inserted when ever I removed the async from the ProcessDataTablePartsResult processedResult = ProcessDataTablePartsAsync(genericCatalogID, excelDataTable); function. I my send this function to the thread pool and give the user a message telling them that this will take a few minutes and to check back in a few minutes for the results, or something to that nature.

Comment: I must be tired because the reason it was stopping at 1,000 rows is because my t-sql started with SELECT TOP 1000. SHEESH!